# How can I change Photoshop's color picker to the default style?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

Somehow my color picker style is changed and I don't like this style because picking color is very difficult.

I want the default style which has single color shades rather than a number of colors. How can I set it back to the default style?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The color field shows colors based on the value you have selected on the right hand side of the picker...

You have the blue "B" from the RGB values selected. The default is the "H" from HSB, so check the "H" to return it to the default.

[image]

See [Choose colors in Adobe Photoshop - Adobe Support](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/choosing-colors.html#adobe_color_picker_overview)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have selected **RGB**, just select the H from **HSB**

[image]

After selecting H:

[image]

Comment: Need to select the "H" specifically. Each (e.g. "S" and "B") is different.